# margin: auto property in CSS3

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Part of my HTML-5 code:

```
<header id="main">
    <a href="#" id="exit"></a>
    <a href="http://www.reddit.com/" id="reddit"></a>
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" id="stackoverflow"></a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" id="facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" id="title"></a> 
</header>
```

CSS-3 code:

```
#main{
    height: 220px;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px #000000 solid;
}

#title{
    float: left;
    background: url(title.jpg) no-repeat;
    padding: 90px 145px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 2px #000000 solid;
}
```

I've set borders on both ID just to make it easier to visualize. I have no idea as to why my title image is not centered. From the code above it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5nWag/2/

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML5 and CSS3, am removing those tags

Comment: @Nilzone- can you provide us with some more css? Or use [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ..

Comment: @CTravel I have posted the JsFiddle if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

title image isn't centered because you are using `float: left;` and i think you are using this for `id="exit"`.
Try to put facebook, stack, red into div with `position: absolute;`. Next do the same for exit.

And this should be style for your main image.

```
background: url(title.jpg) no-repeat;
padding: 90px 145px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
border: 2px #000000 solid;
```

Comment: Ill try this - Thanks. One question though: margin: 0 auto sets top and bottom to 0, and left and right to auto. Why do you set margin-bottom, and margin-top to 20px?